# How create Socket in new Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I want create Socket connection but i have some problem. I must create it in new Thread but i can not.

```
public class SocketManager {
    private static SocketManager instance;


    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private Socket mSocket = null;

    public static SocketManager me() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SocketManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void connection() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    mSocket = new Socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL, 4444);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        return mSocket.isConnected();
    }
```

and

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        SocketManager.me().connection();
        if (SocketManager.me().isConnected()) {
            status.setText("Connected");
        } else {
            status.setText("Disconnected");
        }
```

I have error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.net.Socket.isConnected()' on a null object reference
```

Becouse `mSocket` create in new Thread and when i call it it == null; How can create mSocket in new Thread and use it?

Comment: It seems to me that `SocketManager.me()` is returning null. You need to add null check first.

Comment: you need to wait for socket to actually get created. can you put Thread.sleep(1000) between call to connection() and isConnected() to test it?

Comment: I can add check null, but it meaningless because i dont need mSocket ==null, i nedd mSocket  not null

Comment: you are calling `isConnected` before your asynctask execution finishes

Comment: @ilj i add sleep(3000) and it not helped. And i thik it is not right

Comment: @ Boss I know it captain obvious)))! so I want to know how to do it right

Comment: implement postExecute method and use a boolean variable for check execution completion or use interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use an interface.

Create an interface in your Socketmanager class

```
public class SocketManager {
    private static SocketManager instance;
    private SocketListner listner;

    public interface SocketListner {
        void onConnectionSuccess();
        void onConnectionFailed();
    }

    public void connection(SocketListner listner) {
        this.listner = listner;
        new ConnectionTask().execute();
    }
```

And return a boolean value from `doInBackGround()` method to check if the connection is success or not

```
    class ConnectionTask new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //...your code

        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if(result) {
                listner.onConnectionSuccess();
            } else {
                listner.onConnectionFailed();
            }
        }
    }
```

And in your activity implement the interface

```
 public class YourActivity imlpements SocketListner {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //your code
      ..
    }
    @Override
    void onConnectionSuccess() {
        //your socket is connected
        status.setText("Connected");
    }

    @Override
    void onConnectionFailed() {
        status.setText("Disconnected");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think method "isConnected()" is trying to access mSocket before it is initialized.

Try to change it to:

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    return mSocket == null ? false : mSocket.isConnected();
}
```

This will avoid the NullPointerException on this method.

But the correct approach here would be to use a callback so the child thread can inform the main thread when it has finished.

```
public class SocketTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    public interface AsyncTaskListener<T> {
        void onTaskCompleted(T t);
    }

    private final AsyncTaskListener<String> listener;

    public SocketTask(AsyncTaskListener<String> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
                    mSocket = new Socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL, 4444);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {
        listener.onTaskCompleted();
    }
}
```

You class SocketManager need to implement the callback:

```
public class SocketManager implements SocketTask.AsyncTaskListener {

}
```

Comment: and???? i have mSocket ==null and call isConnected() and returne false so, what is next? i can not worck with mSocket  and i want create mSocket

Answer (score 0):

Add boolean to know your asynctask is complete or not.

```
boolean mIsSocketInstanceCreated = false;

public void connection() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    mSocket = new Socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL, 4444);
                    mIsSocketInstanceCreated = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                   mIsSocketInstanceCreated = false;
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
}

    public boolean isConnected() {
        if (mIsSocketInstanceCreated)
          return mSocket.isConnected();
        return false;
    }
```